# Windows Phone 7 with Silverlight - MediaElement doesn't play with this code

Tags: windows-phone-7

What am I doing wrong please?

it doesn't show any error, and doesn't play.

```
MediaElement song = new MediaElement();
        song.Source = new Uri(@"\WP7_aaa\WP7_aaa\GameSounds\MenuScreen.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(song);
        song.AutoPlay = false;
        song.Play();
```

Comment: oh, I just need to change the LayoutRoot for a grid inside, for example: ContentPanel.children.... =)

Answer (score 1):

In your project, for the MP3 file, have you -

1. set the `Build Action` property to `Content`?
2. set the `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy Always`?

In case you haven't done the above in the project, try them out.

HTH, indyfromoz

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the song to be loaded before you can call the Play method on it.

What you want is:

```
 MediaElement song = new MediaElement();
 song.Source = new Uri("Audio/background.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
 song.MediaOpened += MediaElement_MediaOpened;
```

And then in the event handler:

```
    private void MediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as MediaElement).Play();
    }
```

[See this thread for more details](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/73556/448782.aspx). (edit: no idea where to find this thread now that they split it into WP and Xbox Forums...)

Answer (score 0):

You must specify kind of Uri as RelativeOrAbsolute.

```
MediaElement song = new MediaElement();
song.Source = new Uri(@"\WP7_aaa\WP7_aaa\GameSounds\MenuScreen.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(song);
song.AutoPlay = false;
song.Play();
```